# Is there a substitute for Dijon mustard and if so, what is it?

Tags: substitutions, mustard

Can I substitute a small amount of say, hot english mustard for Dijon, or is there some other alternative. (Of course I will get some soon, but right now i have none, and was wondering if i can make do with something else)

Comment: Can you tell us what you are doing with it? That would make some difference regarding the best substitution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dijon has a strong taste from the liquid they use in it (it's not quite vinegar, not quite wine).  I'd probably try a blend of some other mustard + a little white wine vinegar (not white vinegar; white *wine* vinegar) or champaigne vinegar or apple cider vinegar.  (Maybe even a dry white wine, if you have that on hand).

If you have dry mustard powder, and some time to let it sit, you could also try making your own; most of the recipes online seem to use a dry white wine as their base, a few use white wine vinegar.