# substitute for Dijon mustard

Tags: substitutions, mustard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a substitute for Dijon mustard and if so, what is it?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4440/is-there-a-substitute-for-dijon-mustard-and-if-so-what-is-it)

i want to know if you can substitute Dijon mustard with something else and if so then what?

Comment: In what type of recipe are you substituting it?  Dijon mustard can have many different functions.

Comment: Err, other mustard would be fine as well.